# Reference multiple equations, same parentheses

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref

I have a list of equations that I want to reference all grouped together in the same pair of parentheses (...). How should I proceed? I am aware of the `cleveref` package, which does indeed group equations together, but (as far as I can tell) not within the same parentheses.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}
First equation:
\begin{equation}
    \label{1}
    E=mc^2
\end{equation}
Second equation:
\begin{equation}
    \label{2}
    e^{i \pi}+1=0
\end{equation}
Third equation:
\begin{equation}
    \label{3}
    a^n+b^n=c^n
\end{equation}
Reference with \texttt{eqref}: Eqs. \eqref{1}, \eqref{2}, \eqref{3}

Reference with \texttt{cleveref}: \cref{1,2,3} 

Again with \texttt{cleveref}: \labelcref{1,2,3} 

What I actually want: Eqs. (1,2,3)
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the MWE]

Comment: What should happen if you need to cross-reference five consecutive equations? Should it be "Eqs (1,2,3,4,5)" or "Eqs (1-5)"?

Comment: @Mico Ideally I would like an approach with the option to trigger either the first or the second behavior you describe, similar to [sort&compress] for bibliography referencing. Right now however I need to obtain the first result you propose, that is, "Eqs (1,2,3,4,5)"

Comment: However, I am also interested in how to obtain "Eqs (1-5)", if that is easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am also interested in how to obtain "Eqs (1-5)" ...

Here's how to generate "Eqs (1-5)" with the help of the machinery of the `cleveref` package. I'm afraid I don't know how to generate "Eqs (1,2,3,4,5)".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{Eq}{Eqs} % capitalize "E", no period
\crefrangelabelformat{equation}{(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
\begin{document}
\cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5}. \crefrange{eq1}{eq5}.

% Five equation-related \label directives:
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{eq1}
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{eq2}
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{eq3}
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{eq4}
\refstepcounter{equation} \label{eq5}
\end{document}
```